# Printing Images With Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to plot a 37x37 black&white image, so far I have created a matrix and was hoping to get black pixels for 1's and white pixels for 0's. I dont know what went wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
cols37 = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
rows = []

for i in range (37):
    rows.append(cols37)

mura = np.array(rows, dtype = np.bool)
temp = Image.fromarray(mura, '1')
temp.save('my1.png')
temp.open('my1.png')
```

I am currently getting this image:

[image: current output]

Instead, I am supposed to get something like this:

[image: desired output]

Comment: You want to put in 36 rows of 37 numbers and get out an image with 362x352 pixels?

Comment: you are always appendig the same row... so your output has sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by two issues

- Option `mode` specified with `'1'` will get rawmode `'1;8'`, then it will decode wrong raw data from numpy array, remove option `'1'` will get rawmode `'1'`, also result image with mode `'1'`.
- Same row data in rows, so you won't get right image as requested, or ten vertical black lines in your images.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

cols37 = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]
rows = []

for i in range (37):
    rows.append(cols37)

mura = np.array(rows, dtype = np.bool)
temp = Image.fromarray(mura)        # temp.mode will be `'1'`
```

or

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

cols37 = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]
row_data = [255 if item else 0 for item in cols37]
rows = [row_data for i in range(37)]

mura = np.array(rows, dtype=np.uint8)
temp = Image.fromarray(mura, mode='L')
temp.convert('1')
```

Both scripts will get same image

[image]

Update: Actually, there's only 36 data in `cols37`, here I convert your data from 1D to 2D with NOT+XOR operation , then get picture like yours.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

cols36 = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
row = cols36 + cols36[::-1]

rows = []
for y in range(72):
    line = []
    for x in range(72):
        line.append(not(row[x] != row[y]))
    rows.append(line)
    line = []

mura = np.array(rows, dtype = np.bool)
im = Image.fromarray(mura)        # temp.mode will be `'1'`
im.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this fixed my main issue, i am currently working on fixing the matrix so it will look like in the photo

Comment: Update as above, convert your cols37 as x-data, also as y-data, then got a 2D picture.